# create a connection with a postgresql database using sequel and puma

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel, puma, rubinius

For the past few weeks I've been learning Ruby and I must say that it hasn't been easy to get a grasp of some things.

That leads me to asking this question, I'm trying to setup a project which uses [Rubinius](http://rubini.us) as ruby engine, [puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) as webserver (since Puma states that it's best made to work with Rubinius because of their concurrency implementation), PostgreSQL as database and [sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) as toolkit for the database.

What I'm struggling with is making the database connection. As it is, I'm doing it in the `config.ru`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'uri'
require 'yaml'
require 'erb'


Bundler.require :default, ENV['RACK_ENV']

DATABASE.disconnect if defined?(DATABASE)

if ENV['DATABASE_URL']
  db_config = URI.parse ENV['DATABASE_URL']
else
  #noinspection RubyResolve
  db_config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read('config/database.yml')).result)[ENV['RACK_ENV']]
end

DATABASE = Sequel.connect db_config

require File.expand_path('../application/api', __FILE__)

run APP::API
```

But I've been told that it's not the best place to do it if I want concurrency and not a shared connection. If I were using [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org) I would do it in the `before_fork`, but Puma does not have such a function.

Though it does provide a `on_worker_boot` it is not useful with Sequel, because if I preload the app, Sequel requires a database connection before it can create my models (`class SomeClass < Sequel::Model`).

I am a bit confused now and I'm not sure where to go from this point. I was trying to find some guides or some good practices on this matter, but the only things I found were using ActiveRecord.

Does someone know how to actually do this properly, connecting to the database?

Comment: It would be totally wrong to establish a PostgreSQL database connection before forking anyway. You can't share one socket and connection across multiple workers. You'd need to connect _after_ forking workers.

Comment: @craigringer ~ so what you're saying is that it's fine the way I'm already doing it.

Comment: I don't know the tools involved well enough to say for sure. All I'm saying is that you can't safely share one PostgreSQL connection between multiple forked processes, and you should establish a connection *after* you fork workers from a main process, not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't set up puma to fork and preload the app (`-w` and `--preload` flags), you shouldn't need to do anything.  If you have set up puma to fork and preload, then after loading your model classes, call `DATABASE.disconnect`.  You may also want to lobby the puma developers to add a hook similar to `before_fork` in unicorn.

Comment: thanks for suggesting to close the connection after I load all model classes, yes I do preload the app

Comment: puma has a `before_fork` hook now https://github.com/puma/puma#clustered-mode